# background service with data for later use best practice

Tags: android, android-service

I'm writing an application that needs to register the actual location every minute, whether it's in foreground or background. When the user decides it's time to stop tracking, I want to gather all the data collected and use them.

To do that, I've thought about an architecture that tries to save the battery and it tries to be as efficient as possible. I'm wondering if my choice is decent enough. Here it is:

1. I start a service S from an Activity through startService(). The service will construct a data structure to save data for later use. A communication between the activity and the service will also be created through Messenger objects.
2. I register to location updates that will be managed by a receiver R. It will be something like this:

   ```
   this.lm= (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);        
   Intent locationIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TravelPosition.class);
   PendingIntent locationPendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, locationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 7000, 1, locationPendingIntent);
   ```
3. Each time the receiver R is triggered, it will communicate with the service S. I was thinking about a startService(Intent) where I put the coordinates in the Intent's extras.
4. The service S will store the new data (my new location coordinates and other infos that I generate with them) in its inner data structure. Everything should work whether the app is running in foreground or background
5. Once the user stops the tracking by means of a button in the activity, the latter will communicate with the service to get the data stored until then, then it calls stopService

what do you think about this? 
One more extra question: If a user wants to kill the app, what happens to the receiver? Will it open the app back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are right thinking architecture through before start writing a code :)

Second, I recommend to read following links:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html
http://devdiscoveries.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/android-use-location-services/

Third, In your case, you don't need a service S. You can register receiver R and do everything you need in this receiver R (including processing and saving data). In the case, if you exit from your application, you will still continue to receive location updates.

Comment: So, to recap: I create a BroadcastReceiver somewhere (in my activity) and I register it. After that, I can access it thanks to a simple reference I've kept and I unregister it when I no more need it. Right? :-)
Just for my curiosity: could the architecture I first thought OK for heavier/more complex tasks? Is there a good scenario where I'd better use a service with a receiver?

Comment: That's correct. In the cae if you need to do heavy lifting, then you probably should create a service and create worker threads for processing in this service. The main reason for this is to not block (as I remember Receiver won't be called second time, until first time call isn't finished).

Comment: Thank you so much! Grazie! The solution is already running perfectly

Comment: Hi @VictorRonin I am also working on same type of application in my case i am tracking user data in service and store in database. and in another service i just read from local database and sent it to server. so for location tracking it will be better to use Location update receiver but for second service which sends data. which approach will be good? alarm or network related any receiever?

Comment: @PareshDudhat Frankly, I didn't do anything in this area for quite long time. I would say you will need both. You need some scheduled calls (alarm?) and it would be nice to track state of network (get notifications when it's up and down).